# Task.Parallel updating UI. Why So?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I am able to update UI from code 1 but not from 2.

**Code 1**

```
   Parallel.ForEach(names, name =>
   {
     lblText.Text += "\n" + name + " Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
   });
```

**Code 2**

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(names, name =>
                {
                    lblText.Text += "\n" + name + " Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                });
            });
```

I know that code 2 won't update UI because its a secondary thread. But why code 1 is updating UI? Don't Parallel foreach run different threads? if yes then why it is updating UI?

**output of code 1**

[image]

Comment: Parallel.ForEach reuses the parent thread, which is why it's blocking. One of those threads is actually the UI thread so it has no trouble updating the UI

Comment: but if it uses parent thread then why there are two different thread ids ?

Comment: Where does this code run?

Comment: It *reuses* the parent thread, along with as many others as it deems appropriate. If you have a quad-core and a lot of data it would use 4 threads, including the UI thread. If it's hyperthreaded, it may use 8. Parallel.ForEach is meant for CPU-heavy computations and using more threads than cores will only slow things down

Comment: But still doesn't answer the question why it allows to update that label text from non-ui threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both code segments work... Really.

The problem is that the first code block runs while it blocks the UI thread. The second code block starts the task and then continues.

The problem isn't in the use of multiple threads, since both examples use multiple threads to change the value of the label. The problem is in the state of the form.

I assume you run the code in the form constructor. In the first case, there is no handle created, so **the operation doesn't need the UI thread**. It just updates the backing value. In the second case, in the split millisecond it needs to create the task, it creates the handle for the form. When it needs to update the label **the operation needs the UI thread**.

If you put in a `Wait` on the task you will see it will also work.  If you move the code to the `OnHandleCreated`, it both statements will fail.

Comment: Running the code in a `Click` event results in a cross-thread exception once the second thread tries to update the UI. How did you try it? Where did you run the code? Was it in the constructor or `Load` handler perhaps?

Comment: I ran it from the constructor. If you move the code to the `OnHandleCreated`, it will fail.

Comment: Now that's the real answer.

Comment: Yes, I was running the code from constructor previously and it was working fine. Then I ran it on button click and I got exception.

Answer (score 2):

This code can only work in the constructor of the form. At this point the object has no UI or UI handle, so there is no UI to update.  The code simply changes the property of the label control.

If you try the same code in the `OnLoad` method or in a Click event handler you'll get the expected cross-thread access exception.

The forms and controls on them aren't the real UI objects. Applications send *messages* to the operating system telling which Windows controls to display where, how to modify them etc. The messages are identified by a Windows Handle.

The constructor though executes before the form is even created, so there is no UI to send any messages to. When you update the label text, you just modify the string that contains the value that will be send to the OS once the UI is initialized.

Once the handle is created, any modification of the `Text` property sends a message to the OS, which is explicitly prevented by .NET. The reason is that sending messages from multiple threads will result in out-of-order delivery to the OS and a messed-up UI.

Answer (score -1):

The `Parallel.Foreach` could eventually run the tasks in different threads. Here's an article about how Parallel loops work on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)

Depending on where your code is, you could still use the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method by calling the Invoke method and passing a delegate. This will search up the control's parent chain and find a control that has a window handle.

Your code inside the task would look like this:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.lblText.Text += "\n" + name + " Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? The OP isn't asking why Parallel actually works in parallel. The question is why the forbidden UI update succeeds

Comment: I think the question is "Don't Parallel foreach run different threads? if yes then why it is updating UI?"... How is this not relevant when the MSDN article explains how and why the parallel foreach doesn't always run in different threads.

Comment: The question isn't asking about `Parallel.ForEach`. It's asking about an unexpected UI behaviour